# IQueryable<T> cast to IList<SpecificInterface>

Tags: c#, casting, entity-framework-ctp5

### Setup

```
public interface ITable { }

public class Company : ITable {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PaginationGridModel {

    public PaginationGridModel(IList<ITable> rows) {
        //cool stuff goes here
    }
}

public GridModel GenerateModel<T>(IQueryable<T> Table) where T : ITable {
    return new GridModel((IList<ITable>)Table);
}

//Actual Call
return GenerateModel<Company>(this.dataContext.Companies);
```

### Exception Generated

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Company]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[ITable]'.
```

### Question

Since `Company` implements `ITable` I should be able to convert my `List<Company>` into an `IList<ITable>` however it doesn't want to work because it's actually `T`. But `T` is constrained in the function definition to an `ITable`. What am I doing wrong here? When I'm not using Generics the setup works just fine. However I wanted a Generic setup because I've been writing the same code over and over - which is bad :)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even if what you tell me is that it can't be done.

Comment: Sounds like a job for variance, but I'm not good enough with variance to answer this yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For .NET 3.5 you can use this:

```
return new GridModel(table.ToList().ConvertAll(x => (ITable)x));
```

Comment: Hmm...I should have specified. I actually tried this but Linq to Entities doesn't support casting like that.

Answer (score 1):

If this is .NET 4.0 you could read about generic [covariance and contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).

Comment: +1 for the link. I love to learn new stuff - this will definitely help me to better understand what I'm doing in the future. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx this link from the link you linked me offers a good explanation.

Comment: I accepted the other one simply because you're much higher in point count but your answer was still really good. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the LINQ Cast() extension method:

```
return new GridModel((IList<ITable>)Table.Cast<T>());
```

which is a bit clearer.

Also it is often nicer to use IEnumerable instead of IList when possible.